# How to convert Sun Aug 16 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time) to 16.08.2015

Tags: javascript, date, sharepoint

Iam trying to convert the Sun Aug 16 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time) to 16.08.2015 format but not finding any food solution. Anyone have experience ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
var d = new Date('Sun Aug 16 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200');
console.log(d.getDate()+'/'+ ((d.getMonth()+1)< 10?'0'+(d.getMonth()+1):(d.getMonth()+1)) + '/' + d.getFullYear() ); //16/08/2015
```